# flash-drive is not getting detected in windows 7 ,earlier versions than windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have 16GB Transcend pen drive. Recently I formatted that flash-drive at my Windows 8.0 computer. pen-drive is perfectly working with Windows 8.0 computers and Windows 8.1 computers .

But Once I plug this to Windows 7 or Ubuntu computer , its not detecting at all, just show the indicator light

Comment: What do `Device Manager` and `Disk Manager` show?

Comment: as I said earlier , pen-drive is perfectly working with Windows 8.0 computers and Windows 8.1 computers , but I have Windows 8.0 :(

Comment: Your question relates to Windows 7... on a particular machine... what do `Device Manager` and `Disk Manager` show on the computer where your memory stick isn't showing... I'm trying to get at whether your Windows 7 has even noticed that a USB device has been attached... Your other "working" computers are irrelevant... your memory stick isn't working on a particular computer (or more) so I'm trying to help with this computer - to answer your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer for my problem myself. I installed this [JetFlash Online Recovery](http://www.transcend-info.com/Support/Software-3/) tool and then its repaired my device and reinstalled essential drivers automatically. Now its working.